# PGFPlot | Pretty Scatter Plot with opacity in depth / markes in fog

Tags: pgfplots, plot, transparency

## Having a visability "fog" in the plot

Matplotlib is giving marks a opacity in relation with the distance to the viewer. 
I would like to achieve something similar in pgfplots.

- Is this possible?

Im already using the `point data` options for coloring other data in this plot.

- So is it perhaps possible to add a second `point data` that definse the opacity of the marker (and is mapped in according to the ax that most suitable for the depth)?

### Pictures

Matplotlib:
[image: matplotlib]

PGFPlot:
[image]

### Python Code - Generating Data and Matplotlib Figure

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
n=50
xs = np.random.randint(0,high=100,size=(n))
ys = np.random.randint(0,high=100,size=(n))
zs = np.random.randint(0,high=100,size=(n))
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(xs, ys, zs, c=zs)
ax.set_xlabel('X Label')
ax.set_ylabel('Y Label')
ax.set_zlabel('Z Label')
sdata = [xs,ys,zs]
np.savetxt('data.csv', np.transpose(sdata), delimiter=',', fmt='%i') 
plt.show()
```

### MWE PGF-Plot

```
% Using LuaLatex - other Compiler should also work
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=12cm, height=6cm, view={30}{30},
colormap/viridis,
colorbar,
grid=major]
\addplot3[only marks, scatter]
table[x index=0, y index=1, z index=2, point meta=z, col sep=comma]{data.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Data-Table if needed

```
27,81,45
88,92,23
1,89,41
27,43,0
1,96,19
12,84,71
19,53,24
37,46,95
58,85,35
26,48,37
24,55,79
92,15,71
69,39,82
4,52,29
80,88,75
46,67,64
88,18,34
24,97,31
63,20,57
76,89,71
8,31,50
78,57,46
68,15,40
57,29,73
87,43,21
60,74,40
75,32,58
82,95,83
13,48,54
94,58,67
40,44,8
92,76,40
28,59,43
2,91,40
0,96,48
35,39,52
58,7,38
9,53,81
87,39,9
82,28,7
92,21,52
30,29,69
4,94,37
78,94,86
94,58,76
54,89,39
6,68,84
85,37,93
1,68,67
51,8,62
```

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[view={30}{30},colormap/viridis,colorbar,grid=major]
            \addplot3[only marks, scatter,
                visualization depends on={
                    1-sqrt(((x*sin(30))^2+((100-y)*cos(30))^2)*cos(30)^2+((100-z)*sin(30))^2)/100 \as \markopacity},
                scatter/@pre marker code/.add code={}{
                    \pgfsetstrokeopacity{\markopacity}\pgfsetfillopacity{\markopacity}
                },
            ]
                table
                [x index=0, y index=1, z index=2, point meta=z, col sep=comma]
                {data2.csv};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```