# Variable opacity for tiles in surf plot

Tags: pgfplots, transparency

I would be intereste in doing something similar to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/353895/pgfplot-pretty-scatter-plot-with-opacity-in-depth-markes-in-fog) but for a heatmap (surf plot viewed from above or matrix plot). More precisely using the *z* value to set the opacity of the tiles.

Alternatively, having a colorbar starting from a color and leading to "transparent" would do the trick for me (even though it would be a less general solution).

Here is an example where I would like the white (or black) to be replaced with fully transparent tiles.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\setlength{\PreviewBorder}{0pt}
\PreviewEnvironment[{[]}]{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{
    compat=1.18,
    colormap={mymap}{color(0cm)=(blue);color(1cm)=(transparent!100);}
}

\def\xmin{0}
\def\xmax{9}
\def\ymin{0}
\def\ymax{9}

\begin{document}
%============================================
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    hide x axis, hide y axis,
    axis equal image,
    colormap/blackwhite,
    view={0}{90},
    enlargelimits=false,
    xmin=\xmin, xmax=\xmax,
    ymin=\ymin, ymax=\ymax,
]
    
\addplot3[
    surf, shader=flat,
    domain=\xmin:\xmax, domain y=\ymin:\ymax,
    samples=\xmax+1, samples y=\ymax+1
] gnuplot [parametric=true] {u,v,sin(u+v)};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```